# Write JSON Array without flattening list to a file in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I have created below JSON array in PowerShell

```
$json = @(
        @{
            firstname = "abc"
            lastname = "xyz"
            email = "abc@xyz.com"           
        }
    )
```

When I write json to a file list/array structure is lost
**$json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $filepath**
**$json | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $filePath**
I tried with the above commands, file looks like this

```
{
  "firstname": "abc",
  "lastname": "xyz",
   "email": "abc@xyz.com"
}
```

I want to write json to a file without flattening the list i.e. retain the array format as shown below

```
[
  {
     "firstname": "abc",
      "lastname": "xyz",
       "email": "abc@xyz.com"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipeline will flatten/unravel the array stored in `$json`, so avoid piping to `ConvertTo-Json` at all:

```
ConvertTo-Json $json |Out-File $path
```

Comment: This works. Thank you